# Home page is not getting latest after updating local storage in Agular/ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am fairly new at angular and ionic. I was testing out some mobile development and for some reason, home page is not getting updated with latest valued stored in local storage. Any help is greatly appreciated.

in short, flow is home or folder page (by defualt from ionic) has add button -> takes you to notepage where you can enter headername etc. -> which gets saved in local storage via service. When I am calling service to get latest to show all the notes, nothing is showing up.

please find the code below for your reference in link or pasted below:

Again, thank you for any help!!

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19uQnMDSAq4C23PxTMLc4GhS2NdmbFe2J?usp=sharing

**Code:**

```
**folder.page.ts:**
export class FolderPage implements  OnInit {
  public folder: string;
  public noteList: NotePageComponent[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.folder = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    console.log('folderpage ngOnInit');

    this.localStorage.read().then(data => {
      this.noteList = data;
      console.log('folderpage ngOnInit 2: ' + this.noteList);
    });
  }

  addButtonClick()
  {
    this.router.navigate(['/note-page']);
  }
   

**Note.page.ts:**
export class NotePageComponent implements OnInit {

  public headerName = '';
  public text = '';
  public lastSavedTime = new Date();
  private editMode = false;
  noteList = [];

  constructor(private localStorage: LocalStorageService,
              private router: Router,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('notepage ngOnInit');
    if (this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('name')) {
      console.log('NotePageComponent: ', this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('name'));
      const noteHeaderName = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('name');

      if (noteHeaderName) {
        const note = this.localStorage.getSpecificNote(noteHeaderName).then(data => data = note);
        this.headerName = note.headerName;
        this.text = note.text;
        this.editMode = true;
      }
    }
  }

  okClick() {
    console.log('okClick');
    if (!this.editMode) {
      console.log('okClick non-editMode');
      this.localStorage.addNotePageToList(this);
      this.localStorage.read().then(data => {
        this.noteList = data;
        this.router.navigate(['']);
        console.log('okClick 2: ' + this.noteList);
      });
    }
    else {
      console.log('okClick editMode');
      this.localStorage.updateNotePageToList(this);
      this.editMode = false;
      this.router.navigate(['']);
    }
  }

**local-storage.service.ts:**
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
  })

export class LocalStorageService {

  private noteId = 1;

  constructor(private storage: Storage) { }

  public addNotePageToList(notePage: NotePageComponent)
  {
    const item = { headerName: notePage.headerName, lastSavedTime: notePage.lastSavedTime, text: notePage.text };
    console.log('***inside addNotePageToList', notePage);
    this.noteId = this.noteId + 1;
    return this.storage.set(this.noteId.toString(), JSON.stringify(item));
  }

  public read(): Promise<NotePageComponent[]>{

    console.log('** inside read');
    const notes: Array<NotePageComponent> = [];
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.storage.forEach(data => {
        console.log('***inside foreach', data);
        notes.push(JSON.parse(data));
      });
      return resolve(notes);
    });
  }
```

Comment: It would be better to have the code in your post, for convenience. Also, you need to provide the component code, in which you are using the service in your link. The issue is most likely there.

Comment: @alou the code and service file all are shared in the link above. Here is the code though:

Comment: The only obvious thing Is see is that `read` method is returning a promise of `{ headerName: string, lastSavedTime: string, text: string }[]` not  `NotePageComponent[]` but that doesn't explain your issue. Is the console.log inside storage.forEach showing something? Could you make a stackblitz with your code so that it's easier to follow? https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic

Comment: Hi Alou...thanks for your reply. Read function returns promise of NotePageComponent which is getting parse by Json while adding to the array. I am saving data as string using Json stringify. I can see data being shown but only after I re-compile the app or reload the page. Also, I tried creating the project on stackblitz but I am not able. I tried alot but no luck. Sorry for inconvenience. Please let me know if you are fine with me sharing the app through Github or google drive only if you are comfortable with it else it is fine. Again, I really appreciate your help!!